# Prevent python shell from closing after giving a return

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to output a specific row of a CSV table. All of that works basically just like I want it to in the debugger console of VSC, but when I run the Python script itself, it closes immediately after a value is entered. Shouldn't the `while True` expression prevent that and loop indefinitely?

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
import csv

Liste = []
with open ("wetter.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        Liste.append(row)

while True:
    date = input("enter date:")
    col = [x[0] for x in Liste]
    if date in col:
        for x in range(0,len(Liste)):
            if date == Liste[x][0]:
                print(Liste[x])
    else:
        print("no entries for this date. try again")
```

Comment: How exactly are you running the code? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that you're running the right file? according to your snippet your code should run infinitely

Comment: @Gabip - The code will raise an error if for instance there is a blank line in the CSV. If OP is on Windows and is double clicking to run the file, the window will close so fast the traceback may not be seen. That's why mkrieger1 asked about the environment where the script is run. We just have to sit on our hands waiting for OP to answer the question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Im running the code on windows 10 with Python 3.8.0. I ran it by just double clicking on the python file

Comment: @Gabip Thanks for your answer, I already checked the CSV. It does not contain any blank lines

Comment: As suggested, run your program from the command prompt and see what happens. You are assuming that the csv file is in the current directory, but when you double click, you get a different current directory. You could add `import os;print(os.getcwd());input("continue...")` to see. An absolute path may solve this problem.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried running it with "py wetter.py" and it worked just like in the debugger. So just for my understanding: When I doubleclick the file, its running in another directory than the one it originated from? Am I getting it right?

Comment: @MoritzSanft - Exactly. If you temporarily add code to print current directory, you'll see. You need some mechanism to decide where the file is. Right now, you've got a hard coded file name, it may be reasonable to make that a full path name. I'll add another option to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a try/except block that prompts for final exit to see what the problem is. Since you have several potential errors (the file doesn't exist, the CSV file has a blank line) its good to have some error reporting / recovery code anyway.

```
import csv

try:

    Liste = []
    with open ("wetter.csv") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            Liste.append(row)
    
    while True:
        date = input("enter date:")
        col = [x[0] for x in Liste]
        if date in col:
            for x in range(0,len(Liste)):
                if date == Liste[x][0]:
                    print(Liste[x])
        else:
            print("no entries for this date. try again")
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    input("\nPress any key to exit")
```

Since current working directory is different depending on where you run the program, you may need to hard code the file name or make it something entered by the user. `pathlib` is an interesting if somewhat cryptic way to build paths. If you want to hard code your documents directory for instance, you could

```
from pathlib import Path

documents = Path("~/Documents").expanduser()
filename = documents/"wetter.csv"
```

If you want the user to input filename, then

```
filename = Path(input("enter file name: ")).expanduser()
```

Comment: Oh, that means that when you double click you are running python 2, not 3. You can verify with `import sys;print(sys.version)`. In python 2, `input()` would try to compile what you typed into python - hence the syntax error. In python 3, `input()` just returns the string entered (the same as python 2's `raw_input`).  Python 2 is end of life. If you don't need it, uninstall it. And then you have to figure out how to get the .py file association to work again. Maybe reinstall python 3?

Comment: Thank you so much!! This finally solved the entire problem for me.

Comment: Click the accept button if this solves the problem so that others know we've got a fix.

Answer (score -1):

You can either run the code using Command Prompt

`python filename.py`

OR you can add an `input()` at the end of your code to s

Comment: The `input()` is already there, it’s called in every iteration of the loop (or at least it should, that’s what the problem is).